# Crud Repository method to extract specified data

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have some data stored in the database like this format : `7/07/02 00:00:04`

i want to extract just those whose begin with the date of today `30/08/2017`

i am using crud repository.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement your own method.

I suggest you to have a look at: 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html
It is shown how to implement custom requests with CrudRepositories.

Then have a look there: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html

According the doc, if your date field is called 'startDate' and you have a date object of today 0am called todayDate you can create something which would look like this:

yourRepository.findByStartDateAfter( todayDate )

Can't help you more since there is not a lot of infos ...